# How to use mysqli prepare statement to login with email or username (Not PDO)?

Tags: php, mysqli

I have saw many answer about php login with username or email, but I can't find the resolution of "Mysqli Prepare Statement", all of them used PDO...

My question is, why I can't use two `?` to select username or email?

My code is here:

Database

```
table user
--id int(11) UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
--username varchar(20),
--password varchar(255),
--email varchar(30),
```

html

```
<form action="login.php" id="login_form" method="post">
    <input type="text" name="account" placeholder="username or email" />
    <input type="password" name="password" placeholder="password" />
    <div class="login_submit">
      <button type="submit" name="submit">Login</button>
    </div>
</form>
```

PHP

```
<?php
$con = new mysqli(DB_HOST, DB_USER, DB_PASSWORD, DB_NAME, DB_PORT);
$con->query('SET CHARACTER SET utf8');

if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
    $account = $_POST['account'];
    $get_password = $_POST['password'];
    $login_query = 'SELECT username,password,email FROM user WHERE username = ? OR email = ?';
    $login_stmt = $con->stmt_init();

    if ($login_stmt->prepare($login_query)) {
        $login_stmt->bind_param('ss', $account, $account);
        $login_stmt->execute();
        $login_stmt->bind_result($username, $password, $email);
        $login_result = $login_stmt->get_result();
        while ($login_row = $login_result->fetch_assoc()) {
            $check_password = $login_row['password'];
        }
    } else {
        echo 'Login Error';
        exit();
    }

if ($login_result->num_rows == 0) {
    $account_error = $lang_account_not_exist;
    $login_permit = false;
} elseif (!password_verify($get_password, $check_password)) {
    $password_error = $lang_wrong_password;
    $login_permit = false;
}
```

**EDIT**

```
bind_result($username, $password, $email);
```

Comment: "why I can use two `?` ..." => It wold make no sense to allow only one `?` in a prepared statement.

Comment: They are placeholders. When mysqli (and PDO, since it can also use the ? syntax) executes the query, it will tell your database to use the values you pass into bind_param in place of the question marks, in order.

Comment: On your database are `username` and `email` both set to whatever the user entered in `$_POST['account']`

Comment: Do some error checking. Add `ini_set('display_errors', 1); ini_set('log_errors',1); error_reporting(E_ALL); mysqli_report(MYSQLI_REPORT_ERROR | MYSQLI_REPORT_STRICT);` to
the top of your script. This will force any `mysqli_` errors to
generate an Exception that you can see on the browser and other errors will also be visible on your browser.

Comment: Maybe this is a good time to consult the manual? http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php

Comment: `$login_stmt->bind_result($password);` is not required, possibly causing  other issues

Comment: I dont see any code that is actually making a connection with the database in what you show us. Are you connecting to the the database?? [`mysqli_connect()`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.connections.php)

Comment: @RiggsFolly I have add that code, $con

Comment: The issue is with `mysqli_stmt::bind_result()`. You're selecting 3 columns, but binding only 1 variable.

Comment: @aynber I dont think it should be there at all, or am i wrong

Comment: Pretty sure `$login_stmt = $con->stmt_init();` is not needed either

Comment: @RiggsFolly I don't use mysqli, so I'm not sure. I think the OP should either drop it completely or pass in the correct number of variables.

Comment: @aynber Because my project is too big to change mysqli to PDO, so I want to know how it works on mysqli...

Comment: @RiggsFolly `stmt_init()` is the function which I found it here : [Link](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.stmt-init.php), so.. it isn't needed?

Comment: @Dormilich sorry that's my fault, I mean `why I can not use two ?`

Comment: @carry0987 What does the error message say?

Comment: Ah ha, a properly worded question changes the answer. You *can* use 2 `?` in your prepare statement. That's not the issue you're having. The prepare/bind_param/execute works fine, but (as mentioned before) the error comes from `bind_result` binding 1 variable to 3 columns.

Comment: @Dormilich it said `PHP Warning:  mysqli_stmt::bind_result(): Number of bind variables doesn't match number of fields in prepared statement`

Comment: @aynber I add 3 variable, now it doesn't report any error, but still can't login...

Comment: If there's no error, then you're going to have to do some troubleshooting. Log/echo/var_dump along your code to find out where it's going and what it's doing, and what your variables contain.

Comment: @carry0987 Check the Manual how to use `mysqli_stmt::bind_result()`. Mixing fetch strategies is likely to produce unexpected results.

Comment: @Dormilich I saw the problem, I use undefined variable named $login_username, now I fix it, thanks a lot !

Comment: @aynber I use var_dump and I saw the problem, thanks for your remind !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is probably NOT on

```
$login_stmt->bind_param('ss', $account, $account);
```

As you'd think.

This looks fine, **unless** your `$_POST['account']` is an array and not a single variable, which I doubt. In this case it will fail there. But your WHERE statement and bindparam looks correct

However this is not correct :

```
$login_stmt->bind_result($password);
```

Because you try to bind only one variable and you have 3 columns returned in your SELECT statement (`SELECT username,password,email` )

Since you don't really need the `email` and `username` in your code, just change your query like this:

```
$login_query = 'SELECT password FROM user WHERE username = ? OR email = ?';
```

and it should work