# My PHP Login System doesn't work under the domain site

Tags: php, mysql, authentication, session

I hope this question is not out of the place but this is my last resort and i don't want to fail this lesson so here it goes. I'm having trouble with my login system. My login system works totaly fine under localhost but when i host a site and put this login system on there, sign up works but i can't seem to login. Any suggestions?

Here is my header.php where i show the login form

```
           <?php

                session_start();

            if (isset($_SESSION['userId'])) { 

              echo '<form action="includes/logout.inc.php" method="post">

                <div class="card-body">
                <button class="form-control mr-sm-2" type="submit" name="logout-submit">Log out</button>
                </div>

              </form>';
            }
            else { // 
              echo '<form action="includes/login.inc.php" method="post">

                  <div class="form-label-group">
                  <input type="text" name="mailuid" class="form-control" placeholder="Username/EMail....">
                  </div>

                  <div class="form-label-group">
                    <input type="password" name="pwd" class="form-control" placeholder="Password...">
                    </div>

                    <div class="card-body">
                    <button class="btn btn-lg btn-primary btn-block btn-success " type="submit" name="login-submit">Sign In </button>
                    </div>

                    <div class="card-body">
                      <a class="btn btn-lg btn-primary btn-block " href="signup.php">Sign Up</a>
                    </div>

                    <div class="card-body">
                    <a href=".$loginUrl.">Sign in Through Facebook</a>
                    </div>

                  </form>';

                  include 'google.php';
            }
```

Here is my login.inc.php

```
if (isset($_POST['login-submit'])) {

  require 'dbh.inc.php';

  $mailuid = $_POST['mailuid'];
  $password = $_POST['pwd'];

  if (empty($mailuid) || empty($password)) {
    header("Location: ../index.php?error=emptyfields");
    exit();
  }

  else {
     $sql = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE uidUsers=? OR emailUsers=?;";
     $stmt = mysqli_stmt_init($conn);
     if (!mysqli_stmt_prepare($stmt,$sql)) {
       header("Location: ../index.php?error=sqlerror");
       exit();
     }
       else {
         mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, "ss", $mailuid, $mailuid);
         mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt);
         $result = mysqli_stmt_get_result($stmt);
         if ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {

           $pwdcheck = password_verify($password, $row['pwdUsers']); 
           if ($pwdcheck == false) { 
             header("Location: ../index.php?error=wrongpassword");
             exit();
           }

           elseif ($pwdcheck == true) {
             session_start();
             $_SESSION['userId'] = $row['idUsers'];
             $_SESSION['userUid'] = $row['uidUsers'];

             header("Location: ../index.php?login=success");
             exit();

           }

           else {

             header("Location: ../index.php?error=wrongpassword");
             exit();

           }

         }

         else {
           header("Location: ../index.php?error=nouser");
           exit();
         }
       }


  }

}
else {

  header("Location: ../index.php");
  exit();

}
```

And lastly connection to my database

```
$servername = "localhost";
$dBUsername = "root";
$dBPassword = "";
$dBName = "loginsystemtut1";

$conn = mysqli_connect($servername, $dBUsername, $dBPassword, $dBName);

if(!$conn) {

die("Connection failed " .mysqli_connect_error());

}
```

Any help would muchly appreciated since tomorrow is the deadline.

Comment: Check if all of your files are in their corresponding directories. And also did you try php's error reporting?

Comment: I'm sorry , pardon my ignorance i'm new at PHP so i don't know how that works. Can you elaborate little bit?

Comment: Put this at the top of your php file but under the `<?php` tag: `ini_set('display_errors', 1);
ini_set('display_startup_errors', 1);
error_reporting(E_ALL);`. This should display all errors in that php file.

Comment: I will give that a shot. Thank you so much.

Comment: probably this is your problem `mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, "ss", $mailuid, $mailuid);` giving same value twice and `$mailuid` is uniqe I think should get `i` param and one of `$mailuid` should be `$password` Easy to watch mtuts tutorial again step by step and validate with.

Comment: I wont redirect you wrong but I dont think it will work that way, as I said I am not sure. See this enes might help you : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50136193/how-to-use-mysqli-prepare-statement-to-login-with-email-or-username-not-pdo

Comment: Thank you Dilek for your help. You were right at your comment about it should be password instead of mailuid however i think i have a problem with my .header file because button doesn't seem to redirect.

Comment: @EnesÇalışkan I use pdo so I am not sure and affraid to comment :) , but the link I refered looks like the correct one and exactly same as your, And your button change like this: `<button type="submit" class="btn btn-lg btn-primary btn-block ">Sign Up</button>` as your form action already redirecting to signup page so you dont need href tag in button.

Comment: Are you using "localhost" to connect to a database on your remote web server?

Comment: @JayBlanchard I'm using localhost for testing the website locally but i'm using Linux hosting for godaddy for hosting the site so therefore it works under the domain name